# Why doesn't my Promise add to my array named "arguments"?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm pretty new to JavaScript but have had some other programming experience so I'm picking most of it up (somewhat) quickly. Promises do totally confuse me.

I have a promise that took me a while to cobble together, but I finally got it working. If I call this

```
var test
.
.
 
detectActive().then(function(result) {
    if (result.isActive)
        { alert("ACTIVE"); }
})
```

The alert pops up with the correct result. But instead of the alert, if I try to set the variable 'test' that exists outside of the promise (try to set it inside the promise, where the alert is now) it doesn't have any effect. I'm pretty sure that it is a scope issue.

```js
// (from comments)
console.log(arguments);
detectActive().then(function(result) {
  if (result.isActive) {
    arguments.push("from within promise");
  }
});
arguments.push("after promise");
```

When I try the above first console.log shows empty Array `[]`. arguments.push within the promise returns a log error 'TypeError: arguments.push is not a function'. But the push outside the promise works and logs Array `[ "after promise", "other data in the array" ]`.

What I actually want to do is run the detectActive function and then push a value to an array that exists in the outer function. I think I need to nest another promise. I tried many different versions of this idea all produce code that doesn't run. As I said earlier it took me along time to get the single promise to work.

What is the correct way to achieve what I want?

Comment: It's not clear to me that nesting would be helpful. Setting `test` from within your Promise should have the correct effect, and it's even easier if you're pushing a value to an array: Assigning variables can be tricky with scope, but modifying an array that you can read should be very easy. **Can you show us where and how you're reading `test` that leads you to believe it doesn't work?** Is it DevTools, or in another part of the code that you haven't shown us here?

Comment: Be aware that **any** logic that needs the value of `result` should be place inside that `then` callback  function, or be called from there. Don't expect your script to just continue below that `detectActive()` call and have access to that asynchronous result, because it will not yet be there.

Comment: `console.log(arguments);
detectActive().then(function(result) {
            if (result.isActive)
               {arguments.push ("from within promise"); }
        })
arguments.push("after promise");`

When I try the above first console.log shows empty Array []. arguments.push withing the promise returns a log error 'TypeError: arguments.push is not a function'. But the push outside the promise works and logs Array [ "after promise", "other data in the array" ]

Comment: `arguments` already [has a meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and will be something else inside your inner function. You better change the name of your variable.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it's a scope problem, and only because you're working with a variable named [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) in your function. If you named it anything else it would be fine.

`arguments` is a special automatically-provided variable in JavaScript, which is *array-like* but *not an array*. JavaScript automatically populates it for every function call, which helps make functions work with variable numbers of arguments.

> `arguments` is an array-like object, which means that `arguments` has a [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/length) property and properties indexed from zero, but it doesn't have [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)'s built-in methods like [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). However, it can be converted to a real `Array`, using one of [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Let's try it:

```js
function demonstrateArguments() {  // no explicit arguments
  console.log(arguments.length, ": ", arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]);
}

demonstrateArguments();
demonstrateArguments("a", "b");
demonstrateArguments(1, 2, 3, "no room for me");
```

Consequently, the `function` you define within your Promise defines its own `arguments` variable that doesn't have a `push` function. Even if it did, it wouldn't be the same `arguments` that exists outside the function.

```js
/** Your original function, with labeled console calls. */
function originalName() {
  let arguments = [];
  console.log("original-before:", arguments);
  detectActive().then(function(result) {
    if (result.isActive) {
      arguments.push("from within promise");
      console.log("original-within:", arguments);
    }
  }).catch(console.error);
  arguments.push("after promise");
  console.log("original-after:", arguments);
}

/** Exactly the same, but with "values" rather than "arguments". */
function newName() {
  let values = [];
  console.log("new-name-before:", values);
  detectActive().then(function(result) {
    if (result.isActive) {
      values.push("from within promise");
      console.log("new-name-within:", values);
    }
  }).catch(console.error);
  values.push("after promise");
  console.log("new-name-after:", values);
}

function detectActive() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(res, 1000, /* argument to res = */ {isActive: true}));
}

originalName();
// delay newName call
setTimeout(newName, 3000);
```

Comment: I changed 'arguments' to 'args' and it still doesn't work for some reason. I then moved everything dealing with the array that was outside (and after) the promise to inside the then statement (I think this is what trincottrincot was talking about) and it works. Flow of the program looks ugly to me but it works.

Comment: @J-P Right; Promises are useful because JavaScript won't wait for this asynchronous operation (server call, `detectActive`, permissions prompt, etc). All the stuff that you do with the `detectActive` call needs to wait until that Promise is resolved, so it all has to go into your `then` handler. As you learn more JavaScript you will also be able to use `async function`, which lets you `await` a Promise value and effectively pause a running function until something asynchronous happens to resume the function—but under the hood of `async` it's still just putting everything in a `then` handler.